# error de atributo: el modulo "verificar" no tiene atributo "chequear"

Tags: python-3.x

perdon si esto ya fue contestado pero estuve viendo un poco algunos casos parecidos pero no es lo mismo al mio, por lo menos los que vi.
El caso es que tengo una clase, formuarios.py que debe, una vez introducido una contraseña cualquiera, abrirse paso al formulario indicado en el modulo verificar.py, el problema es que me da el siguiente error al introcuir la contraseña correcta:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1702, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/gerardo/Plantillas/Python/git-aula/formulario.py", line 63, in chequear
    return vf.chequear(self.listaCaja)
AttributeError: module 'verificar' has no attribute 'chequear'

No me reconoce la funcion chequear de modulo verificar y no entiendo porque, si me pueden dar una mano porque no se que no estoy VIENDO, gracias y saludos.
Hay un otro modulo al ultimo para que vean de donde se crean los formularios por si necesitan saber como viene el codigo.

CLASE formularios.py

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
import componentes as cpt
import verificar as vf

""" FORMULARIO DE INGRESO permite accder a la app en si """

class Formularios():

    def __init__(self):

        self.listaCaja=[]
        self.listaBoton=[]
        self.listaEtiqueta=[]
        self.comando=[]
        self.chequear


    #----------- VENTANA ACCESO -----------

    def acceso(self):

        lista=("USUARIO:", "CLAVE:")
        lista2=("ENTRAR", "SALIR")

        raiz=tk.Tk()
        raiz.resizable(0, 0)
        raiz.title("Ingreso de Usuarios")

        marcoUno=tk.Frame(raiz, width="200", height="100")
        marcoUno.grid(column=0, row=0) 

        marcoDos=tk.Frame(raiz, width="200", height="50")
        marcoDos.grid(column= 0, row=1)

        #----------- ETIQUETAS mUNO-----------

        for i in range(len(lista)):
            self.listaEtiqueta.append(cpt.crear_E(marcoUno, lista[i]))
            cpt.ordenar(self.listaEtiqueta[i], i, 0, 5)

        #----------- CAJAS TEXTO mUNO-----------

        for i in range(len(lista)):
            self.listaCaja.append(cpt.crear_C(marcoUno, "20"))
            cpt.ordenar(self.listaCaja[i], i, 1, 5, 5)

        #----------- BOTONES mDOS-----------

        self.comando=[self.chequear, quit]
        for i in range(len(lista2)):
            self.listaBoton.append(cpt.crear_B(marcoDos, lista2[i], "10", self.comando[i]))
            cpt.ordenar(self.listaBoton[i], 0, i, 5, 2, "", 1)


        raiz.mainloop()


    def chequear(self):
        return vf.chequear(self.listaCaja)


    def registrarUs(self):

        listaCaja=[]
        lista=["NOMBRE", "APELLIDO", "DNI", "FECHA", "EDAD", "DIRECCION", "TEL", "MAIL"]
        lista2=["ACEPTAR", "SALIR"]

        ventana=Toplevel()
        ventana.geometry("500x700")
        ventana.resizable(0, 1)
        ventana.title("REGISTRO DE USUARIOS")

        marcoUno=Frame(ventana, width="500", height="650", bg="red")
        marcoUno.grid()
        marcoDos=Frame(ventana, width="500", height="50", bg="green")
        marcoDos.grid()

        def prueba():
            if listaCaja[0].get() == "x" and  listaCaja[1].get() == "a":
                messagebox.showwarning(title="Denegado", message="Su autenticación es Incorrecta")

        comando=[prueba, quit]

        duplicarEtiqueta(marcoUno, lista)
        #ordenarCajas(duplicarCaja(marcoUno, lista))

        for i in range(len(lista)):
            listaCaja.append(crear_C(marcoUno, "40"))
            ordenar(listaCaja[i], i, 1, 5, 5)


        duplicarBoton(marcoDos, lista2, comando, 0)


    def registrarGral(self):
        ventana=tk.Toplevel()
        ventana.title("BIENVENIDO AL AULA")

raiz=Formularios()      
raiz.acceso()
```

MODULO verificar.py

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import messagebox
import formulario as frm


def chequear(lista):
    if lista[0].get() == "adm" and lista[1].get() == "yo":
        formulario = frm.Formularios()
        formulario.registrarGral()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning(title= "Denegado", message= "Su autenticación es Incorrecta")
```

MODULO componentes.py

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk

"""Este módulo está orientado a crear componentes sencillos de un formulario"""

#---------- ORDENAR ELEMENTOS ------------------

def ordenar(obj="", fila=0, col=0, x=0, y=0, coord="", cols=1, rows=1):
    obj.grid(row=fila, column=col,  padx=x, pady=y, sticky=coord, columnspan=cols, rowspan=rows)


#---------- CREAR ELEMENTOS ------------------

def crear_E(contenedor, titulo=""):
    etiqueta=tk.Label(contenedor, text= titulo)
    return etiqueta 


def crear_C(contenedor, ancho="15"):
    caja=tk.Entry(contenedor, width= ancho)
    return caja


def crear_B(contenedor, titulo="", ancho="10", comando=""):
    boton=tk.Button(contenedor, text=titulo, width=ancho, command=comando)
    return boton
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes importaciones mutuas de alto nivel, lo que casi siempre es una mala idea.
En formulario.py importas `import verificar as vf` y en verificar.py importas `import formulario as frm`

Si realmente debes tener importaciones mutuas en Python, la forma de hacerlo es importarlas dentro de una función:

```
# En verificar.py:
from tkinter import messagebox

def chequear(lista):
    import formulario as frm
    if lista[0].get() == "adm" and lista[1].get() == "yo":
        formulario = frm.Formularios()
        formulario.registrarGral()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning(title= "Denegado", message= "Su autenticación es Incorrecta")
```

Ahora `formulario.py` puede seguramente importar `verificar.py` sin causar problemas.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta Junior, pero te consulto, porque decis que las importaciones mutuas son una mala idea y de ser asi como deberia haberlo hecho para que el codigo sea mas eficiente o funcione bien, mi idea es que antes de generar cuanquier fromulario, o al menos los mas importantes pasen por este modulo que controlaria los ingresos de los usuarios,.... saludos